# C# Volatile read behavior

Tags: c#, volatile, memory-model

In the reference source code of the C#.net ConcurrentDictionary ([C# reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs)), I don't understand why a volatile read is required in the following code snippet:

```
public bool TryGetValue(TKey key, out TValue value)
{
    if (key == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("key");
      int bucketNo, lockNoUnused;

    // We must capture the m_buckets field in a local variable. 
    It is set to a new table on each table resize.
    Tables tables = m_tables;
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer = tables.m_comparer;
    GetBucketAndLockNo(comparer.GetHashCode(key), 
                      out bucketNo, 
                      out lockNoUnused,
                      tables.m_buckets.Length,
                      tables.m_locks.Length);

    // We can get away w/out a lock here.
    // The Volatile.Read ensures that the load of the fields of 'n'
    //doesn't move before the load from buckets[i].
    Node n = Volatile.Read<Node>(ref tables.m_buckets[bucketNo]);

    while (n != null)
    {
        if (comparer.Equals(n.m_key, key))
        {
            value = n.m_value;
            return true;
         }
         n = n.m_next;
     }

     value = default(TValue);
     return false;
 }
```

The comment:

```
// We can get away w/out a lock here.
// The Volatile.Read ensures that the load of the fields of 'n' 
//doesn't move before the load from buckets[i].
Node n = Volatile.Read<Node>(ref tables.m_buckets[bucketNo]);
```

confuses me a little bit.

How can the CPU read the fields of n before reading the variable n itself from the array ?

Comment: I'd suggest it's a copy & paste from [elsewhere](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs,787) since the variable names don't precisely match here, when they do in the second example. I'm no closer to discerning the *meaning* behind the comment though.

Comment: http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/Y/You-are-not-expected-to-understand-this.html  You'll have to understand how a processor with a weak memory model works.  They have not done well in the marketplace, only ARM cores really matter today.  Decent blog post [is here](http://preshing.com/20120930/weak-vs-strong-memory-models/).

Answer (score 3):

A volatile read has acquire semantics, which means it precedes other memory accesses.

If it weren't for a volatile read, the next read to a field from the `Node` we just got could be reordered, speculatively, by the JIT compiler or the architecture, to before the read to the node itself.

If this doesn't make sense, imagine a JIT compiler or architecture that reads whatever value will be assigned to `n`, and starts to [speculatively read](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Speculative_execution) `n.m_key`, such that if `n != null`, there's no [mispredicted branch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_predication), no [pipeline bubble](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_(computing)) or worse, [pipeline flushing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hazard_(computer_architecture)#PIPELINE-FLUSH).

This is possible [when the result of an instruction can be used as an operand for the next instruction(s)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operand_forwarding), while yet in the pipeline.

With a volatile read or an operation with similar acquire semantics (e.g. entering a lock), both the C# specification and the CLI specification say it must occur before any further memory accesses, so it's not possible to obtain a non-initialized `n.m_key`.

That is, if the write was also volatile or guarded by an operation with similar release semantics (e.g. exiting a lock).

Without the volatile semantics, such a speculative read could return an uninitialized value for `n.m_key`.

Equally important are the memory accesses perfomed by the `comparer`.  If the node's object was initialized without a volatile release, you could be reading stale, probably uninitialized data.

`Volatile.Read` is needed here because there's no way in C# itself to express a volatile read on an array element.  It's not needed when reading the `m_next` field as it's declared `volatile`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot for a very nice question!
Short answer: comment is wrong (or extremely confusing).
A bit longer answer: there were at least [two bugs in ConcurrentDictionary](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/pull/22382).

`Volatile.Read<Node>(ref tables._buckets[bucketNo])` and `Volatile.Read<Node>(ref buckets[i])` are there to protect us from reading reference that might be changed by another thread, so we have a copy of reference that points to concrete instance of `Node`.

And the bug was that even with these `Volatile.Read` (because it's there not for the reason that was in comment) we can observe partially constructed object of type `Node` if we assign reference with the following code: `tables._buckets[bucketNo] = newNode`.